# Creating std::function with a member function does not compile

Tags: c++, c++14, std-function

I am facing compilation issues with a C++ class.

My code is here:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdint>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

class Monitors {

public:

    Monitors(std::uint32_t timeout1, std::uint32_t timeout2) : timeout_1(timeout1), timeout_2(timeout2) {
        timer_start(task_1, timeout1); //does not compile
        timer_start(&Monitors::task_2, timeout2); //does not compile either

    }

private:

    void timer_start( std::function<void(void)>& func, std::uint32_t interval) {
        std::thread([func, interval]() {
            while (true) {
                func();
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(interval));                }
        }).detach();
    }

    void task_1() {
    }

    void task_2() {
    }


private:

    std::uint32_t timeout_1;
    std::uint32_t timeout_2;
};
```

The error is:

> non const lvalue to type std::function cannot bind to a temporary of
>   type void

What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please be careful with that `sleep_until` call. Think about what happens if the execution of `func` is longer than `interval`. Changing the order you do things will solve that problem.

Comment: Yes, I modified the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler needs to convert the member function to a `std::function<void()>` object to match the `timer_start` function argument list.

This object is a temporary object, whose lifetime will end once the call to `timer_start` is done. And temporary objects can't be bound to non-constant references (this is what the error message is saying).

The simple solution is to pass the function *by value* instead.

```
void timer_start( std::function<void(void)> func, uint32_t interval)
```

---

A second problem is that for member function you always need to use the address-of operator to get a pointer to it. And you always need to specify the class as well.

Which means you need to do

```
timer_start(&Monitors::task_1, timeout1);
timer_start(&Monitors::task_2, timeout2);
```

---

Finally a third problem: Non-static member functions are special, in that they need an object to be called on. This object is what becomes the `this` pointer inside the function.

The object that the function is called on is normally passed as a hidden first argument, but when using e.g. `std::function` we need to specify that argument explicitly.

So the final declaration needs to be

```
void timer_start( std::function<void(Monitors*)> func, uint32_t interval)
```

This last thing also means that you need to pass a pointer to an object to the function, in your case you can pass `this`:

```
// Capture this
//           vvvv
std::thread([this, func, interval]() {
    while (true) {
        auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
        func(this);
        //   ^^^^
        // Pass this as argument
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
    }
}).detach();
```

Comment: No, still does not compile. either &Monitors::task_N or task_N

Comment: @CaptainNemo Updated my answer